# cannot resize window properly to 1/4 and resize back to original size

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I cannot resize window properly to 1/4 of the screen when the minimize button is clicked and resize back to the whole screen in the next click. when the minimize button is clicked,

```
this->setMaximumSize(400, 400);
```

works, but it overwrites previous window and the other parts of the UI still remain on the screen. The ui does not become smaller. Similarly, when I click minimize again to maximize UI, it again does not become bigger to the original size

```
ui->widget_display->setGeometry(200, 0, 791, 800);
```

I used the update() method, but still does not render the mainwindow from the beginning.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   if(minimized == false)
   {
      this->setMaximumSize(400, 400);
      ui->widget->hide();
      ui->widget_display->setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 400);
      minimized = true;

      update();
   }
   else
   {
      this->setMaximumSize(1152, 864);
      ui->widget->show();
      ui->widget_display->setGeometry(200, 0, 791, 800);
      minimized = false;

      update();
   }

   qDebug() << "Minimizing";
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code appropriately. `qDebug() << "Minimizing";` looks like being either at the wrong place, or wrong text. Either way, what is `ui`? The class created by the QtDesigner, or some other home-made?

Comment: qDebug() is ok. ui is MainWindow class ui. Ui::MainWindow *ui;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like the code following

```
this->setMinimumSize(400, 400);
this->setMaximumSize(1152, 864);
```

to set widget to maximum size, use showMaximized method of QWidget.

```
ui->widget->showMaximized(); //i think, it will be the way to call showMaximized(), from your code
```

Refer QWidget Public Functions and Public Slots, http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html

I hope something from this will be helping you.